# Shouldn't this flow type default assignment give me an error?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm barely learning flow, but according to the documentation, the following code should be giving me an error since I'm destructuring the object and assigning a default value to 'overrideKeyProp' that is not a boolean.

This is Ok, no errors:

```
type KeyGenCfgType = {|
  topic: Topic,
  keyProp?: string,
  overrideKeyProp?: boolean
|};

function cfgTypeKeyGen(kGen: KeyGenCfgType) {
  const { keyProp, overrideKeyProp = 1 } = kGen;
}
```

This gives me an error for the non-matching type on property overrideKeyProp:

```
type KeyGenCfgType = {|
  topic: Topic,
  keyProp?: string,
  overrideKeyProp?: boolean
|};

function cfgTypeKeyGen({ keyProp, overrideKeyProp = 1 }: KeyGenCfgType) {
}

//number: This type is incompatible with boolean
```

This also gives me an error:

```
type KeyGenCfgType = {|
  topic: Topic,
  keyProp?: string,
  overrideKeyProp?: boolean
|};

function cfgTypeKeyGen(kGen: KeyGenCfgType) {
  const { keyProp, overrideKeyProp = 1, nope } = kGen;
}
// property `nope`: Property not found in object type
```

So it's able to recognize that I'm attempting to destructure out a property that is not in the flow type I defined for it, but it does not recognize that I'm not assigning a correctly typed value on the property unless I do the destructuring in the function's signature.

Comment: Put the code in the question, not an image. We can not copy paste text from an image.

Comment: @epascarello Done. I have no idea what I was thinking. I also added other examples of the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing is that when you haven't given a type to Flow for a given variable declaration, it will infer the type.

```
function someFunc({ someProp = 1 }: SomeType) {}
```

explicitly says "the type is an object with these properties, make a variable called `someProp` with that property's type. Assigning a number in this case is clearly an error because you've explicitly said what the type should be with `: SomeType`.

```
let { someProp = 1, unknownProp } = fnArg;
```

will fail because Flow knows with certainty that `unknownProp` is not a property available on the `fnArg` object.

So to your question, let's look at your example

```
function someFunc(fnArg: SomeType) {
    let { someProp = 1 } = fnArg;
}
```

- You've declared the function input type, so Flow knows that `someProp` exists on the object, and flow knows what type `fnArg.someProp` is.
- You've assigned a default of `1`.

That's it. You have *not* told Flow what type the `someProp` variable should be. You could do

```
let { someProp = 1 }: SomeType = fnArg;
```

which would throw the error that you are expecting.

What Flow is doing instead is inferring the type. Since it sees that in one part you're doing `let someProp = fnArg.someProp`, it could be a `string`, but in another branch of the code you're doing `let someProp = 1`, so it could also be a number. You haven't done anything to tell Flow that `someProp` has to be a string.

You see similar behavior in Flow in general code:

```
let someVal;
if (Math.random()){
    someVal = "a string";
} else {
    someVal = 4;
}
```

This isn't an error, Flow infers that `let someVal;` is `let someVal: number|string;`.

You can see the same in code like yours if you try to [use the field for something](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKcAtngCq4EC8YA3qmGDgE5w4BcYAzhiwJYA7AOaoAvgG50UAK6CAxhn5xBYDAAshwgBRwARgCsuxMpXwBKeozDyVveq3ZhaARjHOw+g1KbWYeDDAoFy5eAREPRxwfMH9AqAAmLkEZEj08Fki2aPEgA)

```
type SomeType = {
  prop: string
};

function thing(obj: SomeType) {
  const {prop = 1} = obj;

  let f1: string = prop;
  let f2: number = prop;
}
```

which errors with

```
let f1: string = prop;
                 ^ number. This type is incompatible with
let f1: string = prop;
        ^ string
let f2: number = prop;
                 ^ string. This type is incompatible with
let f2: number = prop;
        ^ number
```

because the `prop` is neither a number nor a string, it is both as far as the type system is concerned.

So it is up to you to either explicitly declare the types of a given binding, or to write your code so that the inference will work.